# How to subdivide curve segment without changing its shape?

Tags: bezier-curves

I have a primitive bezier curve circle and when I subdivide 2 points, it changes the shape of the curve. How can I subdivide without changing the curve's shape?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, you've already asked the question, maybe show some screenshots?

Comment: hi @moonboots, pics were added

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address the raised issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the handle type to Free, then subdivide:

[image]